# Is there a mathematical symbol for "among all"?

Tags: statistics, functions, notation

Let there be a set C of discrete values, and a function f be defined for all values belonging to C.
Say we define the dependent variable t as:

> *t = xₖ such that f(xₖ) is maximum among all values of f(xᵢ) where xᵢ belongs to set C.*

which may also be written as:

> *t = xₖ : f(xₖ) is maximum among all values of xᵢ, xᵢ∈C*

I am looking for a symbol to represent "among all values of" in the above context. Note that the for all values of (∀) symbol does not suffice.

Comment: Not a symbol, but this is called the argmax - the argument of the maximum.

Comment: @sean that works here. I was expecting a symbol that would work in other contexts too, which probably does not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do:

$$t = \underset{x_k\in C}{\mathrm{argmax}}f(x_k)$$

For something more general, maybe you can use the $\forall$ symbol by saying something like $t = x_k : \forall x_i, f(x_k) \geq f(x_i)$

Comment: I wouldn't know what you meant by the notation that you propose using $\forall$, particularly as $f(x_k) > f(x_k)$ is false.

Comment: fixed to f(x_k) >= f(x_k). What's the better way to use $\forall$ to say something like this? Is it to put $\forall x_i$ to the end?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you put the quantifiers at the beginning or the end (just don't use both as the result is ambiguous in general). I would be inclined to use plain variable names: the subscripts aren't adding any value. Finally (although it is not widely used, because most authors would use words instead), the symbol for "choose an $x$ such that ..." is Hilbert's $\varepsilon$ operator. So I'd end up with: $t = (\varepsilon x, \forall y, f(x) \ge f(y))$, but I'd need to remind people what the $\varepsilon$ means.